# Disable foreign key in dbunit test

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, oracle11g, junit4, dbunit

I am using dbunit 2.5.4 with junit 4, Java 8, and an oracle db (11 something). I successfully downloaded my test db to a flat file (xml) following online tutorials. I now want to do a CLEAN_INSERT but I get a CyclicTablesDependencyException. The solution appears to be to turn off the foreign key checks but I am not sure how to do this. How can I disabled foreign key checks in my dbunit test when I am doing a clean_insert?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling useSequenceFiltering:  `useSequenceFiltering = false`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all that (up to "Oracle") is (yes, I know, Google is my friend, but only if I use it).

However, if you want to move that "test DB" (is it really a *database*? Or is it a *schema*? I presume the latter, but - even if it is a former, no problem), I'd suggest you to use

- Data pump Export (and Import), or
- *original* EXP (and IMP) utilities

The first one is more powerful, but EXP & IMP are somewhat simpler to use (don't require access to DB server, you don't have to create a *directory* (an Oracle object), DMP file resides on your computer).

What is the export/import benefit? In your case Oracle will take care about constraints. Besides, you'd export all objects by default (tables, views, procedures, triggers, packages, sequences, ... - everything) in a simple manner. I'd suggest you to look at it.

Documentation is, as usual, on OTN (pick your *11 something* version, although - for such a simple requirements - any version will do).

Here's a short demonstration: I'm exporting MIKE's objects (not that many of them) and importing them into SCOTT's schema.

```
M:\>exp mike/lion@orcl file=mike.dmp

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Uto Tra 10 07:11:42 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Tes
Export done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting foreign function library names for user MIKE
. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms
. exporting private type synonyms
. exporting object type definitions for user MIKE
About to export MIKE's objects ...
. exporting database links
. exporting sequence numbers
. exporting cluster definitions
. about to export MIKE's tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                           DEPT          4 rows exported
. exporting synonyms
. exporting views
. exporting stored procedures
. exporting operators
. exporting referential integrity constraints
. exporting triggers
. exporting indextypes
. exporting bitmap, functional and extensible indexes
. exporting posttables actions
. exporting materialized views
. exporting snapshot logs
. exporting job queues
. exporting refresh groups and children
. exporting dimensions
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully without warnings.

M:\>imp scott/tiger@orcl file=mike.dmp full=y

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Uto Tra 10 07:13:51 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Tes

Export file created by EXPORT:V11.02.00 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by MIKE, not by you

import done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
. importing MIKE's objects into SCOTT
. . importing table                         "DEPT"          4 rows imported
Import terminated successfully without warnings.

M:\>
```